# MySQL server has gone away in Clever Cloud database

Tags: python, mysql

I was working on a discord bot and was coding it in python using discord.py that would let users play a hangman game and also store their stats in a mysql database. Initially it was hosted from my local machine and a local database was used. But now, I am hosting it on Heroku and got a free database from clever cloud(10 MB). But at night I slept and in the morning I checked the logs. It was when someone tried to play, I got this:

```
2020-12-21T04:44:00.812958+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_message
2020-12-21T04:44:00.821815+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-21T04:44:00.821823+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 506, in cmd_query
2020-12-21T04:44:00.821824+00:00 app[worker.1]: raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
2020-12-21T04:44:00.821882+00:00 app[worker.1]: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: MySQL server has gone away
```

It happened when the database connection was not used for some time. I don't think I have full control of the server so I was thinking, if I run a script with a `select` query which would be executed every 10 seconds, will my connection still be lost? Or is there some other **more practical** method that would prevent the database from "going away"?

Answer (score 1):

Have look in the docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html) about this issue
Try changing your [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) to a value high enough so that the connection is not inactive for more than that period of time.

Comment: yea i definitely tried that but clever cloud is not giving me permission to change that.